# RTMP streaming using FFMPEG and HLS conversion in NGINX

Tags: c++, nginx, ffmpeg, http-live-streaming

i have some ffmpeg code in c++ that generates a RTMP stream from H264 NALU and audio samples encoded in AAC. I'am using NGINX to take the RTMP stream and forwards to clients and it is working fine. My issue is that when i use NGINX to convert the RTMP stream to HLS, there is no HLS chunks and playlist generated. I use ffmpeg to copy the RTMP stream and generate a new stream to NGINX, the HLS conversion works.

Here is what i get when i do the stream copy using FFMPEG :

```
Input #0, flv, from 'rtmp://127.0.0.1/live/beam_0'
Metadata:
Server          : NGINX RTMP (github.com/sergey-dryabzhinsky/nginx-rtmp-module)
displayWidth    : 1920
displayHeight   : 1080
fps             : 30
profile         : 
level           : 
Duration: 00:00:00.00, start: 5.019000, bitrate: N/A
Stream #0:0: Audio: aac, 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 128 kb/s
Stream #0:1: Video: h264 (High), 1 reference frame, yuv420p(progressive, left), 1920x1080 (1920x1088), 8000 kb/s, 30 fps, 30.30 tbr, 1k tbn, 60 tbc

Output #0, flv, to 'rtmp://localhost/live/copy_stream':
Metadata:
Server          : NGINX RTMP (github.com/sergey-dryabzhinsky/nginx-rtmp-module)
displayWidth    : 1920
displayHeight   : 1080
fps             : 30
profile         : 
level           : 
encoder         : Lavf57.83.100
Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High), 1 reference frame ([7][0][0][0] / 0x0007), yuv420p(progressive, left), 1920x1080 (0x0), q=2-31, 8000 kb/s, 30 fps, 30.30 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc
Stream #0:1: Audio: aac ([10][0][0][0] / 0x000A), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 128 kb/s
```

There are not much differences between the two streams, so i don't really get what is going wrong and what i should change in my C++ code. One very weird issue i see is that my audio stream is 48kHz when i publish it, but here it is recognized as 44100Hz :

```
Output #0, flv, to 'rtmp://127.0.0.1/live/beam_0':
Stream #0:0, 0, 1/1000: Video: h264 (libx264), 1 reference frame, yuv420p, 1920x1080, 0/1, q=-1--1, 8000 kb/s, 30 fps, 1k tbn, 1k tbc
Stream #0:1, 0, 1/1000: Audio: aac, 48000 Hz, 1 channels, fltp, 128 kb/s
```

UPDATE 1 :

The output context is created using the following code :

```
pOutputFormatContext->oformat = av_guess_format("flv", url.toStdString().c_str(), nullptr);
memcpy(pOutputFormatContext->filename, url.toStdString().c_str(), url.length());
avio_open(&pOutputFormatContext->pb,  url.toStdString().c_str(), AVIO_FLAG_WRITE));
pOutputFormatContext->oformat->video_codec = AV_CODEC_ID_H264 ;
pOutputFormatContext->oformat->audio_codec = AV_CODEC_ID_AAC ;
```

The audio stream is created with :

```
AVDictionary *opts = nullptr;
//pAudioCodec = avcodec_find_encoder(AV_CODEC_ID_VORBIS);
pAudioCodec = avcodec_find_encoder(AV_CODEC_ID_AAC);

pAudioCodecContext = avcodec_alloc_context3(pAudioCodec);

pAudioCodecContext->thread_count = 1;
pAudioFrame = av_frame_alloc();

av_dict_set(&opts, "strict", "experimental", 0);
pAudioCodecContext->bit_rate = 128000;
pAudioCodecContext->sample_fmt = AV_SAMPLE_FMT_FLTP;
pAudioCodecContext->sample_rate = static_cast<int>(sample_rate) ;
pAudioCodecContext->channels = nb_channels ;
pAudioCodecContext->time_base.num = 1;
pAudioCodecContext->time_base.den = 1000 ;

//pAudioCodecContext->time_base.den = static_cast<int>(sample_rate) ;

pAudioCodecContext->codec_type = AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO;
avcodec_open2(pAudioCodecContext, pAudioCodec, &opts);


pAudioFrame->nb_samples     = pAudioCodecContext->frame_size;
pAudioFrame->format         = pAudioCodecContext->sample_fmt;
pAudioFrame->channel_layout = pAudioCodecContext->channel_layout;
mAudioSamplesBufferSize = av_samples_get_buffer_size(nullptr, pAudioCodecContext->channels, pAudioCodecContext->frame_size, pAudioCodecContext->sample_fmt, 0);

avcodec_fill_audio_frame(pAudioFrame, pAudioCodecContext->channels, pAudioCodecContext->sample_fmt, (const uint8_t*) pAudioSamples, mAudioSamplesBufferSize, 0);

if( pOutputFormatContext->oformat->flags & AVFMT_GLOBALHEADER )
    pAudioCodecContext->flags |= AV_CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER;

pAudioStream = avformat_new_stream(pOutputFormatContext, 0);

pAudioStream->codec = pAudioCodecContext ;
pAudioStream->id =  pOutputFormatContext->nb_streams-1;;
pAudioStream->time_base.den = pAudioStream->pts.den =  pAudioCodecContext->time_base.den;
pAudioStream->time_base.num = pAudioStream->pts.num =  pAudioCodecContext->time_base.num;

mAudioPacketTs = 0 ;
```

The video stream is created with :

```
pVideoCodec = avcodec_find_encoder(AV_CODEC_ID_H264);

pVideoCodecContext = avcodec_alloc_context3(pVideoCodec);

pVideoCodecContext->codec_type = AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO ;
pVideoCodecContext->thread_count = 1 ;
pVideoCodecContext->width = width;
pVideoCodecContext->height = height;
pVideoCodecContext->bit_rate = 8000000 ;
pVideoCodecContext->time_base.den = 1000 ;
pVideoCodecContext->time_base.num = 1 ;
pVideoCodecContext->gop_size = 10;
pVideoCodecContext->pix_fmt = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P;
pVideoCodecContext->flags = 0x0007 ;

pVideoCodecContext->extradata_size = sizeof(extra_data_buffer);
pVideoCodecContext->extradata = (uint8_t *) av_malloc ( sizeof(extra_data_buffer) );
memcpy ( pVideoCodecContext->extradata, extra_data_buffer, sizeof(extra_data_buffer));

avcodec_open2(pVideoCodecContext,pVideoCodec,0);

pVideoFrame = av_frame_alloc();

AVDictionary *opts = nullptr;
av_dict_set(&opts, "strict", "experimental", 0);
memcpy(pOutputFormatContext->filename, this->mStreamUrl.toStdString().c_str(), this->mStreamUrl.length());
pOutputFormatContext->oformat->video_codec = AV_CODEC_ID_H264 ;

if( pOutputFormatContext->oformat->flags & AVFMT_GLOBALHEADER )
    pVideoCodecContext->flags |= AV_CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER;

pVideoStream = avformat_new_stream(pOutputFormatContext, pVideoCodec);


//This following section is because AVFormat complains about parameters being passed throught the context and not CodecPar
pVideoStream->codec = pVideoCodecContext ;
pVideoStream->id = pOutputFormatContext->nb_streams-1;
pVideoStream->time_base.den = pVideoStream->pts.den =  pVideoCodecContext->time_base.den;
pVideoStream->time_base.num = pVideoStream->pts.num =  pVideoCodecContext->time_base.num;
pVideoStream->avg_frame_rate.num = fps ;
pVideoStream->avg_frame_rate.den = 1 ;
pVideoStream->codec->gop_size = 10 ;

mVideoPacketTs = 0 ;
```

Then each video packet and audio packet is pushed with correct scaled pts/dts. I have corrected the 48kHz issue. It was because i was configuring the stream through the codec context and the through the codec parameters (because of waarning at runtime).

This RTMP stream still does not work for HLS conversion by NGINX, but if i just use FFMPEG to take the RTMP stream from NGINX and re-publish it with copy codec then it works.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: FLV does not normally support 4800khz, So 44100, mono is written to the container. Then it is overridden with the AAC sequence header. How are you creating the stream in the mysterious `ffmpeg code in c++`? Is that something you wrote? Are you inserting the proper sequence headers?